# Integration goniometric functions with using substitution

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am a bit lost how to proceed this integration (I got a recommendation to use substitution here) with goniometric functions in here. I know the correct result, but still can't determine it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply set $u = \text{tg} x$. Then $du = \sec^2 x \, dx$ and the integral reduces to $\int u \, du$.

Comment: What's the $sec^2xdx$?

Comment: @user984621 Notice that $du = \sec^2 x \, dx$ is equivalent to $(du/dx) = \sec^2 x$. In other words, $\sec^2 x \, dx$ is the differential $du$.